# Why does web browser drop down not update the price?

Tags: c#, forms, html-select

I have a program that automatically selects each value inside a drop-down list and copy each of their own price.

The problem I have is that, even though my program selected a particular value--that particular value did not show its own particular price.

This is the code that I am using:

```
foreach (HtmlElement htmlElement in this.webBrowser2.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select")) {
    if (htmlElement.OuterHtml.Contains("msku-sel-1")) {
        htmlElement.Focus();
        // htmlElement.RaiseEvent("onClick");
        htmlElement.InvokeMember("Click");
        htmlElement.SetAttribute("value", "3");
        //webBrowser2.Document.InvokeScript("(a)");
    }
}
```

This is the link of the website that I am applying it on: http://www.ebay.com/itm/Keurig-Tullys-French-Roast-Decaf-18-or-180-K-Cups-/111042016413?

In that web page, there is a drop down list that represents the "Box Size."

So based on that code above, it can highlight and select the Box Size, and then select a value, which is 48.

It should also update and show the price, but it did not.

Now if you manually click the drop down list, and select 48, the price would turn to  "US $39.47"

But the code that I am using above can select the value, but the price does not change to "US $39.47"

As I dug the website's source code even deeper using Opera Internet Browser, I noticed it had an event listener, which contains the following code:

```
function(a){return typeof f!="undefined"&& (!a||f.event.triggered!==a.type)?f.event.dispatch.apply(i.elem,arguments):b}
```

This is the part where I need help with. If you could please recreate the code that I am using, you will notice it will successfully select the right value, but it does not seem to update the price. How do I update the price even though I already selected the value?

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
htmlElement.RaiseEvent("onChange");
```

and place it after selecting the value.

Answer (score 0):

That page has jQuery loaded in it, so you could shorten you code (and address your problem) with:

```
$("#msku-sel-1").val(3);
$("#msku-sel-1").change();
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: could you please clarify more on that?

Answer (score 0):

I FOUND THE ANSWER

I was using Internet Explorer version 9. I downgraded it to Internet Explorer version 7, thus and then when I ran my program, it selected the value and the price that is representative of that particular value successfully showed up